# mysql for PHP only working for some

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, mysqli

I have created a website, using PHP & HTML, it involves submitting data to an SQL database, but it is only adding the data to the database for only some people. It is completely random for who it works for and who it doesn't.

The SQL server is hosted on the same server as the website and I have checked my SQL code in phpmyadmin to ensure it works.

The PHP code where the data is submitted to the SQL server is below:-

```
<?php
#CHANGING POST VARS TO REG VARS
$submit = $_POST['Submit'];
$ign = strtolower($_POST['ign']);
$name = $_POST['rname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

if (isset($_POST['past_yes'])){
    $pe = "1";
}else{
    $pe = "0";
}

if ($ign !== "" and $name !== "" and $email !== "" and $age !== "" and $reason !== "" and $duration !== "" and isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "wadmin", "CENSORED", "DibDibCraft-API");
    $data = "INSERT INTO `custom_staffapp`
    (`ign`,`name`,`email`,`age`,`reason`,`past`,`duration`,`date`)
    VALUES('$ign','$name','$email','$age','$reason','$pe','$duration', '$date')";
    mysql_query($conn, $data);
    mysql_close($conn);
    sleep(0.5);
    $ign = "";
    $name = "";
    $email = "";
    $age = "";
    $reason = "";
    $duration = "";
    $pe = "";
    header("Location: http://www.dibdibcraft.com/staff/apply_done");
}else $error = true;
?>
```

The fill code, including the HTML can be found here: http://pastebin.com/vn8HReRG

I don't know whether this is an error in my code, as the PHP checker I use says there is no issues, or if it is an issue with the server I am using.

I have tried `mysqli_query()`, and the `mysqli` equivalent for all `mysql` functions I have used, and the same problem still persists.

**Server Details**

OS: Ubuntu Server 15.04

RAM: 4GB

PORTS: All Open

WEB SERVER: Apache2

LAMP: Installed with MYSQL Client

Please, let me know of any recommendations you would suggest, whether I need new software on the server or whatever.
PS: All files to do with the website have 775 permissions (so everyone can read & execute them), if that helps.

Thanks in advance for any assistance, Aaron :)

BTW: This is **not** a duplicate because there is no question like this on here, and if there is, it has not been answered.

Comment: It is a dupe. You are not using parametrized queries and are hitting quoting issues which break your sql, beside being a major security problem.

Comment: Sorry to sound like a noob, but how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide an example that reproduces the problem? I suspect that it happens because you use the user provided data directly within your sql. For. e.g. if some one would use double quotes within your reason textarea than this will corrupt your sql. Use mysql_real_escape_string() to prevent such problems (even better are prepared statements).

Comment: first, edit your question to remove your domain name. like, right now.

Comment: then read this and use that api. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: So, can someone please, just post an answer as to how I would format this, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it in a very simple way. It might not be the best way to do it, but it is a one-liner (for each variable) and it works perfectly in my case!

Instead of inserting a variable, to the database, like this; `$reason = $_POST['reason'];`

I have used the `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()` functions in PHP.
So, when submitting data to the database, you do something like this;

```
$reason = "My name is 'aaron'";
$reason = addslashes($_POST['reason']);
echo($reason);
```

This would return;

> My name is \'aaron\'

And then, to remove the slashes, you use the `stripslashes()` function:-

```
$reason = stripslashes($reason);
echo($reason);
```

This would return;

> My name is aaron

Thanks to everyone that answered, but this seems like the best, easiest and fastest way to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the problem is the code-breaking, happened due to user's input of single & double quotes.
I would propose the following quick solution. Filter all the input before saving it to database.

Add the following in the beginning of the file

```
function filter(&$array) {
$clean = array();
foreach($array as $key => &$value ) {
    if( is_array($value) ) {
        filter($value);
    } else {
        $value = trim(strip_tags($value));
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $data = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $data = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
 }
}

filter($_POST); # filters $_POST and any nested arrays by reference
```

The above function will recursively filter all the elements and sanitize them for concatenation to the `INSERT INTO` sql statement. And your script shouldn't misbehave while saving into database.

Comment: How do you read from the database with this then, coz when I come to read the data, it won't display anything...

Comment: Answer updated... The usage is expected to make all insertions to the database successful, in case the problem is input sanitization. Reading from database is another task.

Comment: kk, thanks.
I would vote you up, but I'm a new user so I can't. Soz.